# How to change nested object attribute using JavaScript spread operator?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object like below

```
const obj = {
    name: 'Jone',
    location: {
        presentAddress: {
            livingAddress: {
                City: {name: 'New York'},
                Country: {name: 'USA'},
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to change city name New York to London

So, I have tried below code

```
console.log({
    ...obj,
    location:{
        ...obj.location,
        presentAddress:{
            ...obj.location.presentAddress,
            livingAddress: {
                ...obj.location.presentAddress.livingAddress,
                City:{
                    ...obj.location.presentAddress.livingAddress.City,
                    name: "London"
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

It's working fine, My question is has there any shorter way to do this change?

Comment: _"using spread operator"_ - Why don't you just change the value of the property? If you need a new object then use on of the deep-clone answers here on SO first. That hard-coded `...` construct is just awful...

Comment: @Andreas sorry, I changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the nested property directly.

```
obj.location.presentAddress.livingAddress.City.name = "London"
```